# Count total occurrences that 'Item A is Blue' within two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of data:

```
Item A    blue
Item B    blue
Item B    pink
Item A    pink
Item C    yellow
```

I would like to get the total occurrences that 'Item A is blue'. I assume this is an easy formula and wouldn't require VBA scripting.

Comment: You want to look into `COUNTIFS`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - this is perfect.